# PG::ConnectionBad: PQsocket() can't get socket descriptor: ROLLBACK on deleting record

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

Running:

```
Price.find(208999).delete
```

in a *rails console*, leads to the error message:

```
SQL (0.0ms)  DELETE FROM "prices" WHERE "prices"."id" = $1  [["id", 208999]]
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ConnectionBad: PQsocket() can't get 
socket descriptor: DELETE FROM "prices" WHERE "prices"."id" = $1'
```

Subsequent retries of the same command results in:

```
SQL (4.0ms)  DELETE FROM "prices" WHERE "prices"."id" = $1  [["id", 208999]]
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ConnectionBad: PQconsumeInput() server 
closed the connection unexpectedly
This probably means the server terminated abnormally
before or while processing the request.
: DELETE FROM "prices" WHERE "prices"."id" = $1
```

At this point my I can't run any query commands without running into this problem. Before I run the delete, I can delete another SQL on a different table.

I've tried all the other links on stack overflow relating to this error:

I don't have any spec/rspec rake tasks set, however I have tried *rails tmp:clear* which states, *"# Clear cache and socket files from..."*

I have checked to see if there are any associations made to this record to another table, however me search returned nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching...

The issue was that in my price.rb model file, I had the following relationships stated:

```
class Price < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :card

    has_and_belongs_to_many :collections

    has_many :types

    class << self # Class methods
    end
end
```

I deleted the *price.types* association records however I didn't go the other way and delete the *card.prices* association records.

So the commands I ran where:

```
price = Price.find(208999)

card = price.card

#delete price_card association record
card.prices.delete(price)

#now i'll be able to delete the price record
price.delete
```

There really needs to be a better error message for this, as I've been modifiying my database.yml file and resetting my sockets because that's what the error message leads you to believe.

Hopefully, this will help others before they move onto messing around with the database configuration.

---

### Edit 2

Just had this problem again, I updated to the latest version of PostgreSQL which is 12.4 as I read [dba stackexchange answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/226581/207998) this was a common problem when issuing the DELETE sql command in PostgreSQL 11 which is what I was running on.

And it didn't fix the issue.

After downloading and looking closely at the logfiles pgAdmin4 produces, I found a reference to a relational key, so I created a small script to loop through all records, and set any foriegn key values to `nil` so when it came to deletion, it didn't throw any nasty errors.

```
Product.all.each do |product|
  product.update(cardset_id:nil,language_id:nil)
  product.delete
end
```

### Edit 3

So I finally figured out the true reason why my PostgreSQL database was going crazy..

I have a table called Cards which has a slug field which has `unique: true` option set.

In my Card model, I have a function

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id (:slug_id), use: :slugged

def slug_id
    [
        [:name, :cardset_id],
    ]
end
```

A slug is created, through the mixing of the name and the cardset_id, however if I want different copies of the same record, it is for some reason creating the same slug id.

When PostgreSQL goes to fetch this record, it breaks because the data doesn't make sense and it shouldn't have existed in the first place.

So there is something wrong with my slug function not operating as intended.

Before deleting each record, I simply set the slug to a random value, and then deleted it.

Comment: When a connection disappears unexpectedly, where would the better error message come from?  You can't send an error message over a connection which no longer exists.  Whatever is going on, it is not as straightforward as your answer suggests.  Foreign key constraint violations are routine and *should* not cause the server to fall over.  Look in the PostgreSQL server's log file to find the message it reports.

Comment: You make a valid point, I will have a look at the server logs to find the underlying issue.